# aid with div and checkbox for a better look

Tags: html, css

I have this sign up webpage that I created with help thanks to people here. I just making a few adjustments before trying to make it responsive. How do I create space between the checkbox and its text and the div in the bottom sticks without a gap. Any suggestions?

https://jsfiddle.net/yh12c61k/

```
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 text-center">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="logo-signup">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="uv.png">
            </div>

            <div class="signup-header">
                <div class="row"> 
                    <label class="uv-header">United Volunteers</label>
                    <label class="sm-title">Register Using Your Social Media Account</label>
                </div> 
            <br>  
                <div class="row"> 
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-facebook-signup">Register With Facebook</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-gmail-signup">Register With Google+</button>
                </div>
        </div>  
        </div> 
    </div> 

    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 ">
        <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="signup-form2">
                    <label class="signup-title"><span>Personal Information</span></label>

                        <input type="text" class="signup-input" placeholder="First Name">
                        <input type="text" class="signup-input" placeholder="Last Name">

                        <form>
                            <br>
                                <select name="Month" class="signup-input" style="width:15%">
                                    <option value="Month" disabled selected >Month</option>               
                                    <option value="January">January</option>
                                    <option value="February">Febuary</option>  
                                    <option value="March">March</option>
                                    <option value="April">April</option>
                                    <option value="May">May</option>
                                    <option value="June">June</option>
                                    <option value="July">July</option>
                                    <option value="August">August</option>
                                    <option value="September">September</option>
                                    <option value="October">October</option>
                                    <option value="November">November</option>
                                    <option value="December">December</option>                
                                </select>

                                <select name="Day" class="signup-input" style="width:15%">
                                    <option value="Day" disabled selected >Day</option>
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                    <option value="6">6</option>
                                    <option value="7">7</option>
                                    <option value="8">8</option>
                                    <option value="9">9</option>
                                </select>

                                <select name="Year" class="signup-input" style="width:15%">
                                    <option value="Year" disabled selected >Year</option>
                                    <option value="2010">2010</option>
                                    <option value="2009">2009</option>
                                    <option value="2008">2008</option>
                                    <option value="2007">2007</option>
                                    <option value="2006">2006</option>
                                    <option value="2005">2005</option>
                                    <option value="2004">2004</option>
                                    <option value="2003">2003</option>
                                    <option value="2002">2002</option>
                                    <option value="2001">2001</option>
                                    <option value="2000">2000</option>          
                                </select>

                                <div>
                                    <br>

                                <label><input type="radio" value="male" checked="" name="gender">Male</label>
                                <label><input type="radio" value="female"checked="" name="gender">Female</label>               
                                </div>
                        </form>

                   <label class="signup-title"><span>Address Information</span></label>
                        <form>
                                <select name="Country" class="signup-input" style="width:15%">
                                    <option value="Country" disabled selected >Country</option>               
                                    <option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
                                    <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>  
                                    <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
                                    <option value="Laos">May</option>
                                    <option value="Malaysia">June</option>
                                    <option value="Myanmar">July</option>
                                    <option value="Philippiness">August</option>
                                    <option value="Singapore">September</option>
                                    <option value="Thailand">October</option>
                                    <option value="Vietnam">November</option>
                                </select>
                                    <input type="text" class="signup-input" placeholder="City" style="width:15%">
                                    <input type="text" class="signup-input" placeholder="Additional Information">
                        </form>
                        <br>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-register">Retrieve Location</button>

                    <label class="signup-title"><span>Skills</span></label>

                                <div class="checkbox-signup col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-2">
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="handyman" checked="" name="gender">Handyman</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox-signup col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-2">
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="medic"checked="" name="gender">Medic</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class=" checkbox-signup col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-2"> 
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="artist"checked="" name="gender">Artist</label>               
                                </div>

                                <div class=" checkbox-signup col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-2">
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="cookery" checked="" name="gender">Cookery</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class=" checkbox-signup col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-2">
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="mentor"checked="" name="gender">Mentor</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class=" checkbox-signup col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-2"> 
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="ecologist"checked="" name="gender">Ecologist</label>               
                                </div>

                                <div class=" checkbox-signup col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-2">
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="tech_guru" checked="" name="gender">Tech Guru</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class=" checkbox-signup col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-2">
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="pet_rescue"checked="" name="gender">Pet Rescue</label> 
                                </div>
                                <div class=" checkbox-signup col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-2">
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="social_savvy"checked="" name="gender">Social Savvy</label>               
                                </div>

                     <label class="signup-title"><span>Volunteering Area</span></label>
                        <form>
                                <select name="Country" class="signup-input" style="width:15%">
                                    <option value="Country" disabled selected >Country</option>               
                                    <option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
                                    <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>  
                                    <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
                                    <option value="Laos">May</option>
                                    <option value="Malaysia">June</option>
                                    <option value="Myanmar">July</option>
                                    <option value="Philippiness">August</option>
                                    <option value="Singapore">September</option>
                                    <option value="Thailand">October</option>
                                    <option value="Vietnam">November</option>
                                </select>
                                    <input type="text" class="signup-input" placeholder="City" style="width:15%">     
                        </form>      
                     <label class="signup-title"><span>Account Information</span></label>
                        <div class="account">
                            <input type="text" class="signup-input" placeholder="Username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="account">
                            <input type="text" class="signup-input" placeholder="Password">
                            <input type="text" class="signup-input" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="account">
                            <input type="text" class="signup-input" placeholder="email@website.com">
                        </div>
                         <button type="submit" class="btn-register">Register</button>
                </div> <!-- signup-form -->
        </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
    </div> <!-- col --> 

body {
    background-color: #d00025;
    background-image: url(hands%20banner.jpg);
    background-position:top;
    background-size: 50%;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.signup-header {
    top:90px;
    position:relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 25px auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 25px 50px 50px 50px;
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 2px #330000;
}

.signup-input {
    width: 30%;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family:Candara;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.signup-form2 {
    top:90px;
    position:relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 25px auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:1000px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 2px #330000;
    z-index: 1;
}

.uv-header{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:35px;
    font-family:Candara;
    float:left;
    padding-left:225px; 
}

.sm-title {
    float:left;
    padding-left:225px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:Candara;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.sm-signup{
    font-size:35px;
    font-family:Candara;
    float:left;
    padding-left:225px; 
}

#logo-signup {
    top:70px;
    left: 15%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    position:absolute;
    background-color: white;
    background-size: 170px auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 170px;
    width: 170px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 5px solid white;
    box-shadow: 1px 3px 2px grey;
    z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:35px;
    font-family:Candara;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 100px auto 50px auto;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.account{
    padding-bottom:25px;
}

span{
    background:#fff; 
    padding:0 10px;
}

.signup-title{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    width:100%; 
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    line-height:0.1em;
}

.social_media {
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    top:-75px;
}

.label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:Candara;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.btn-signup {
    background-color: firebrick;
    font-family:Candara;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid firebrick;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 4px #330000;
    width: 200px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:200px;
    display:block;
}

.btn-register {
    background-color: firebrick;
    font-family:Candara;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid firebrick;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 4px #330000;
    width:30%;

}

.btn-facebook-signup {
    background-image: url(fb.gif);
    background-color: #3b5998;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px grey;
    margin: auto;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    width: 250px;
    padding-left:40px;
    font-family:Candara;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
}

.btn-gmail-signup {
    background-image: url(g+.gif);
    background-color: #dc4a38;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px grey;
    margin: auto;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    width: 250px;
    padding-left:40px;
    font-family:Candara;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
}

.social_media-signup {
    display:inline-block;
}

input[type="radio"]{
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `margin-right` to your checkbox:

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

and for the gap in the bottom add `margin-bottom` to the last child the body

```
body div:last-child{

  margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

[**Working demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/yh12c61k/3/)

Comment: Thanks the checkbox, it worked :). However the padding-bottom had no effect

Comment: I edited my answer...add margin-bottom to the last child of the body :)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/yh12c61k/2/ I added a `margin-right: 10px;` on the checkboxes and it looks much nicer

`input[type="checkbox"]{
    margin-right:10px;
}`